# CSS Transitions On/Off on Click

Tags: jquery, css

http://codepen.io/DylanEspey/pen/Cvwzo

The goal is to get the animation to play on click, and then reverse itself on a second click. I'm not sure as to how to use the Javascript to set this up (just now learning it, you see.). I had the idea to add a class using jQuery, below, but it wasn't working. I tried to "cheat" using the :target selector, but that's not really functional. Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function (){
        $(function () {  
        $("#button").click(function () {  
            $("#button").toggleClass(".active");  
        });  
    });  
});
```

Comment: drop the '.' from the class name you are passing into `toggleClass`

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbgae

Markup:

```
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#button">
                <div id="button">
                    <div class="plus">+</div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="banner">
                <p>Some text for your viewing pleasure!</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.active {
        color: red !important;
    }
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
        $("#button").click(function () {  
            $(this).toggleClass("active");  
        });  
});
```

You just needed to drop the . from the .active in your toggleClass.

Secondly, you didn't have an active class in that fiddle above, but I'm guessing you already knew that.

Good luck with your app.

Answer (score 0):

You set invalid paramater in toggleClass function. Just set a string without dot like for example:

```
$('.foo').toggleClass('active');
```

I forked your codepen and made a few changes. You can see working version here: http://codepen.io/hinok/pen/wLlht